# changing style dynamically through jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an input and an anchor.

I can change the color of anchor by `.css({"color":hex})`

But cannot change the style of hover and click.

```
a:hover and a:active
```

these two attributes

Comment: Just so you know. That duplicate answer won't address your issue though. Why not just addClass so you can then define it in your stylesheet?

Comment: @Adrianopolis I also want to change the color of hovering dynamically

Comment: Hi Stan, you can not do that unless you apply a classname. If you look at all third party libs like bootstrap for example you will notice when you hover over elements and the color changes it is because a hover class has been added to the element or it has been defined in the stylesheet.

Comment: I could have gotten a bit of help that 'duplicate' question was about .hover()

Comment: Why didn't I think of that... :o)

Comment: Thank you Jeremy Harris, Praveen Kumaar.!